# Copying some contents and putting to a variable using shell script

Tags: shell

suppose we have "token=1234" content present in a filename. how to get the complete value 1234 and store it in variable called token in shell script

So that I can use $token to use it

Comment: what do you mean by `filename`? did you mean in filename's content ? or filename only ?

Comment: Hello Chandan! Be wellcome to Stackoverflow! If you are talking about a token present in the filename itself provide example of filename in order for your question to be more clear. A valid example of filename would be something like that: "any_name_1234"? What are the rules of such filename? Will it have a fixed size? Will the token be preceded by an underscore, an hyphen? Help us to help you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash, `eval` is your friend.

```
eval "token=1234"

echo $token # should give you 1234
```

Also, can you explain what content present in a filename means? Are you trying to parse the file name or the file's content?

If it's the latter you can just execute your script like any other script:
./yourfile.sh

Comment: `eval` is for arbitrary code. `declare` is for variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the file **contains** just the line `token=1234` then:

```sh
source filename
echo "$token"
```